# prototype not working within web worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Simply speaking   I am trying to prototype a function within a web worker and chromium is throwing this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<DedicatedWorkerContext> has no method 'compute'`

I figure some sample code is needed. It is the end of my work day, so I am throwing this together real quick. It's been boggling me all afternoon. I am hoping its one of those problems I come back tomorrow morning and say "ah-hah" but on the off chance I wont, I thought I'd ask here too.

#### page.js

```
function threaded() { 
   var thread = new Worker('worker.js');
   thread.postMessage({a: 1 b: 2});
   thread.onMessage = function (e) { 
     console.log(e.data)
   });
}
threaded();
```

#### worker.js

```
var foo = function(a,b) { 
   this.a = a
   this.b = b
   this.result = false;
   this.compute();
};

foo.prototype.compute = function() { 
   this.result = this.a * this.b;
};

onmessage = function(e) { 
   var msg = foo(e.data.a,e.data.b)
   postMessage(msg)
};
```

I've also tried arraigning worker.js differently to include foo() within onmessage as follows, but received the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'a' of undefined`

#### worker-take2.js

```
onmessage = function(e) { 

   var foo = function(a,b) { 
      this.a = a
      this.b = b
      this.result = false;
      this.compute();
    };

   foo.prototype.compute = function() { 
     this.result = this.a * this.b;
   };

   var msg = foo(e.data.a,e.data.b)
   postMessage(msg)
};
```

Comment: Btw, it won't work not in a web worker either. So it worth checking it in a "normal" environment first before asking "prototype not working within web worker"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're executing `foo`, rather than declaring a `new` instance of it. Thus, `this` within the context of `foo` evaluates to the dedicated worker context, rather than the object instance context.

Try this out:

```
var foo = function(a,b) { 
   this.a = a
   this.b = b
};

foo.prototype.compute = function() { 
   return this.a * this.b;
};

onmessage = function(e) { 
   var msg = new foo(e.data.a,e.data.b).compute();
   postMessage(msg)
};
```

There's a few important changes to be aware of.  Firstly, I changed `compute` to return the result, rather than set it as a property.  Remember, when using `prototype` you're explicitly creating methods that are shared across object instances, thus implying your use of that code in an object oriented fashion.

Second, I changed the constructor of `foo` so that it doesn't call `compute` immediately. Instead, `compute` is called after declaring an object instance.

Try it out!

Comment: "Ah Hah!", sigh. I knew the answer would smack me in the face. I think I'll just chalk this up to all the snow in New England and just getting over food poisoning...yeah, that's it. Really though, I found myself moving away from new in my JavaScript so much recently. No `var x = new Array();` but `var x = [];`. 

The second point I fail to grasp. for me compute() is actually `init()` that calls a few more methods. Why move that out of the original function declaration?

Comment: Well, I assumed you wanted to preserve the object oriented pattern here, and in the original example you set result, in compute, if you wanted to preserve that you could do: `var f = new foo(e.data.a, e.data.b); var msg = f.result` Honestly, you don't need an object here, just do: `function compute(a, b) { return a * b }` and `var msg = compute(e.data.a, e.data.b);`

Comment: Ah ok. Actually the object is a laundry list of a validation. Which is rather heavy in terms of computation. So I am using a web worker and a series of functions. The object is helping me organize all the functions. In other words, that sample code was just quick and dirty to illustrate the problem I was having in the shortest amount of code. Thanks again for the answer. I knew it would be that simple when I saw it.